# 404 File not found exception when calling ASP.NET webapi

Tags: android, asp.net, post, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-404

When I'm trying to POST a parameter from android to asp.net web api, I got file not found exception. But the same web api is working with postman. Please suggest in which part I should need to correct?

Android code is :

```
 public String CallWebAPI()
       {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("name", "Rahul")
           .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://www.xxxx.co/testapi/TestNameWEBApi")
            .post(formBody)
            .build();

    Call call = client.newCall(request);
           Response response = null;
           try {

               response = call.execute();
               Log.e("ATTEST", "App1 Error is :" + response.toString());

           } catch (IOException e) {
               Log.e("ATTEST", "App1 IOException is :" + e.toString());

               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           return response.toString();
}
```

And webAPI is :

```
   [RoutePrefix("testapi")]

    [Route("TestNameWEBApi"), HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage TestNameWEBApi(string name)
    {
        try
        {
            var Response = name;
            var Result = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Response, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
            return Result;//return same parameter to check if the value is reaching here or not
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
            HttpError Error = new HttpError(ex.Message) { { "IsSuccess", false } };
            return this.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: is there a route on your controller?

Comment: yes RoutePrefix is set as testapi

Comment: check your class  to inheritance Controller or if webApi inheritance from ApiController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your request is missing the query parameter name**.

```
RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
    .add("name", "Rahul")
    .build();
```

The code above adds the name and data to the body, not the URL.

You are probably getting a **404 Not Found** because your server requires the name parameter to be present, or else it will not match the full route.

Remove the name and data from the body, and add them to the URL instead.

```
 public String CallWebAPI() {

 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
 RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
     .build();

 Request request = new Request.Builder()
     .url("http://www.xxxx.co/testapi/TestNameWEBApi?name=Rahul")
     .post(formBody)
     .build();

 Call call = client.newCall(request);
 Response response = null;
 try {

     response = call.execute();
     Log.e("ATTEST", "App1 Error is :" + response.toString());

 } catch (IOException e) {
     Log.e("ATTEST", "App1 IOException is :" + e.toString());

     e.printStackTrace();
 }
 return response.toString();
}
```

The body is completely empty in this case, but you can add to it once the route is working.

There is probably a better way to add query parameters to the URL, but this should work.

Comment: Also I used the [FromBody] to force the method to read the request body and I used a model to get the values passed by the client. The method automatically gets the values from the request and sets them to the model making it very easy.